# Django Query Not Refreshing

Tags: django, django-views

I have built a Django site to list current and upcoming Service outages.   The query is not refreshing unless I restart the Apache service.  It will grab new messages I add but there is inconsistency.

I am running it on the following.

- Apache 2.2
- Postgres 9.2
- Django 1.5.1
- Windows 2008

The view is

```
class MessageViewMixin(object):

    queryset = Message.objects.filter(message_type__id=1
                 ).filter(inactive=False  
                 ).filter(start_time__range=(now, nextweek)
                 ).order_by('-start_time', '-end_time')
    context_object_name = 'upcoming_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MessageViewMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_list'] = Message.objects.filter(
                            inactive=False
                        ).filter(
                            Q(message_type__id=1) | Q(message_type__id=2)
                        ).filter(
                            Q(end_time__isnull=True) | Q(end_time__gte=now)
                        ).filter(start_time__lte=now
                        ).order_by('-start_time', '-end_time')
    return context
```

So upcoming_list is a query for outages in the coming week.  When the outage is occurring the message should now fall under the current_list.  This is not happening unless I restart Apache.

Comment: it could be caching due to `context_object_name = 'upcoming_list'` - try removing that

Comment: That seems to have done it.  I don't understand why changing the context name would cause a caching issue.  I am going though the docs now to try to understand.

Comment: I guess it is like this: `context_object_name` is like a key that is in the context, since the object doesnot change on subsequent requests, it is assuming nothing has changed, and the cache is not invalidated, so it ends up giving the same resultset from the cache every time

Comment: It was the fact the variables now and nextweek were defined outside the class.  They were populated but on startup and the query used stale dates.  Moved the variable inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about this issue [here](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2012/05/30/querysets-arent-as-lazy-as-you-think/).

To summarize that post, although the queryset is indeed lazy and is only evaluated when the view is called, the definition of `now` is not. As Tomita says, the answer is to define it in `get_queryset`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is exactly what you should expect. You put your query in the class definition. It's immediately evaluated and assigned to the variable `queryset`.

Instead, override `get_queryset` which is called every time..

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return  Message.objects.filter(message_type__id=1
                 ).filter(inactive=False  
                 ).filter(start_time__range=(now, nextweek)
                 ).order_by('-start_time', '-end_time')
```